# Can Rust cargo features contain a value?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a program that has two slight variations. I've added a feature in in Cargo.toml like this:

```
[features]
anchor = []
```

In my program, every anchor app has an ID. I know environment variables are the way to go normally, but I'm not sure they work in embedded environments...

Is it possible to embed a value in the feature that can be read by the code?

```rust
if cfg!(feature = "anchor") {
    runner.add_program(AnchorProgram::new(/* anchor ID */));
}
else {
    runner.add_program(MasterProgram::new());
}
```

Comment: Won't this code work as written?

Comment: @Cerberus On the second line in the code, I put a comment where the ID is supposed to go. It works if I put a number in there, but I'd like that to be part of the configuration

Comment: Features can only be turned on or off, and you can't pass in a parameter using them. You could use an environment variable, though, if you really want to.

Comment: Do you want to run the _compiler_ in the embedded environment, or are you cross-compiling from your development machine? If the latter, it doesn't really matter whether your target platform supports environment variables, since you are only using them at compile time.

Comment: @SvenMarnach You are right: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.env.html
The env! macro is at compile time. I thought it was at runtime. Thanks!